LocationMatch regex, a directory + front page
I want to proxy everything except front page and /images/* to another server with password. I wrote
<LocationMatch "^/$|^/(?!images/)">
AuthType basic . . .

ProxyPass "http://anotherserver.example"
</LocationMatch>

But it does not work. ^$ instead of ^/$ did not work either. Images are served as I want, going to /foo/bar.html asks for password and then gives content of http://anotherserver.example/foo/bar.html. Is there something special in regexp handling in LocationMatch?

You got your logic the wrong way around ... ^/$ should match perfectly fine, when just / gets requested - but in that case you do not want to apply password auth and proxying. (Plus, ^/(?!images/) on its own, also matches on / already.)

Uh, got blind to own code. And still can't figure out how to make this to work.

Maybe try to do it via an <If> expression instead, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html The operator !~ can be used to demand a regex not match the test string (so negate some "positive" expression like (^/$|^/images/?)), or if that doesn't work, you can combine multiple expressions with && as well.

ProxyPass can't be used inside If. Anyways, I got this:
<LocationMatch "^/(?!images/)"> <If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ /^\x2F$/"> <If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ /^\x2Findex.html$/"> AuthType basic  . . . RewriteRule "/var/www/html/(.*)" "http://otherserver/$1" [P] </If> </If> </LocationMatch>
